# Is there a way to correct content "expanding" behavior caused by fr sizing when zooming out in browser?

Tags: html, css

I created the following form layout with CSS grids, and as the gif shows, zooming out in the browser causes the content seem to expand while shrinking, instead of just shrinking the content towards the center as a whole [just like with zoomed out stackoverflow](http://prntscr.com/1320ukh).

I've tried to use pixels instead of fr to size my containers and it solves my issue, but using fr for sizing grid columns gives much more precision and convenience.

Is there a solution for this or is it to just stop using fr for css grids?

[image]

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
label {
    display: block;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#checkout {
    margin: 20px 100px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 
        "shipping payment" auto/
        3fr 4fr
    ;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
}

.form1 {
    display: grid;
    padding: 15px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.form1 input, select {
    width: 100% ;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    
}



#shipping {
    grid-area: shipping;
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}



#payMethod {
    grid-area: payment;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    justify-self: end;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #013CA6;
    color: white;

    font-size: 18px;

}

.payment-method {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  20px 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    
}

.pay-label {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 
        "img label" 
        "img description" /
        50px 1fr
    ;
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
}
.pay-description {
    grid-area: description;
}
.payImg {
    grid-area: img;
}

#header {
}
.two-cols {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.required {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="orderingStyle.css">
    <title>Checkout Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">

    </header>
    <main>
        <form id="checkout">
            <section id="shipping" class="form1">
                <h2>Shipping Address</h2>
                     <div class="two-cols">
                        <div>
                            <label for="fName">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="lName">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="phoneNum">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="stAddress">Street Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="stAddress" id="stAddress" placeholder="Street Address: Line 1" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="province">Province <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <select name="province" id="province" required>
                            <option value="Abra">Abra</option>
                            <option value="Agusan del Norte">Agusan del Norte</option>
                            <option value="Agusan del Sur">Agusan del Sur</option>
                            <option value="Aklan">Aklan</option>
                            <option value="Albay">Albay</option>
                            <option value="Antique">Antique</option>
                            <option value="Apayao">Apayao</option>
                            <option value="Aurora">Aurora</option>
                            <option value="Basilan">Basilan</option>
                            <option value="Bataan">Bataan</option>
                            <option value="Batanes">Batanes</option>
                            <option value="Batangas">Batangas</option>
                            <option value="Biliran">Biliran</option>
                            <option value="Benguet">Benguet</option>
                      
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="city">City <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <select name="city" id="city" placeholder="Please select a city" required>
                            <option value="Alaminos">Alaminos</option>
                            <option value="Angeles">Angeles</option>
                            <option value="Antipolo">Antipolo</option>
                            <option value="Bacolod">Bacolod</option>
                            <option value="Bacoor">Bacoor</option>
                            <option value="Bago">Bago</option>
                            <option value="Baguio">Baguio</option>
                            <option value="Bais">Bais</option>
                            <option value="Balanga">Balanga</option>
                 
                        </select>
                    </div>
               
            </section>
            <section id="payMethod">
                   
                <h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 10px;">Select Payment Method</h2>
              
                <div class="payment-method">
                    <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="BDO" id="bdo" required/>    
                    <label class="pay-label" for="bdo"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="BDO icon"/>
                        <p>BDO Online Installment</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Up to 12 months installment term based on installment price. Promo price may not be applicable.</p>
                    </label>
        
                </div>
                
                <div class="payment-method">
                    <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="Metrobank" id="metrobank"/>
                    <label class="pay-label" for="metrobank"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="Metrobank icon"/>
                        <p>Metrobank Online Installment</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Up to 12 months installment term based on installment price. Promo price may not be applicable.</p>
                    </label>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="payment-method">
                   
                    <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="COD" id="cod"/>
                    <label class="pay-label" for="cod"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="Cash on Delivery icon"/>
                        <p>Cash on Delivery</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Within P30,000 and Metro Manila, Cavite, Laguna only.</p>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="payment-method">
                    <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="GCash" id="gcash"/>
                    <label class="pay-label" for="gcash"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="GCash icon"/>
                        <p>GCash</p>
                        <!--<p class="pay-description">Within P30,000 and Metro Manila, Cavite, Laguna only.</p>-->
                    </label>
                    
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="PLACE ORDER">
            </section>
        </form>
    </main>
   
   

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack overflow is aligned to the center of the viewport with an automatic margin, so when you zoom out, it's anchored to the center. Zooming out just essentially increases or decreases the size of the viewport and then scales everything up or down to fit within your browser window.

Comment: You can do the same thing SO does by giving your content a fixed maximum width and `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the the form elements in an additional `div` use that as your grid container and set a max width to the form, centering the grid container.

```css
#checkout {
  /*Adjust max width as required*/
  max-width:2000px;
  /*Center the contents*/
  margin: 0 auto;  
}

#checkout .wrap {
  margin: 20px 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "shipping payment" auto/ 3fr 4fr;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
}



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form1 {
  display: grid;
  padding: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.form1 input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#shipping {
  grid-area: shipping;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}

#payMethod {
  grid-area: payment;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  justify-self: end;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #013CA6;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.payment-method {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
}

.pay-label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "img label" "img description" / 50px 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
}

.pay-description {
  grid-area: description;
}

.payImg {
  grid-area: img;
}

#header {}

.two-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.required {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="orderingStyle.css">
  <title>Checkout Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">

  </header>
  <main>
    <form id="checkout">
      <div class="wrap">
        <section id="shipping" class="form1">
          <h2>Shipping Address</h2>
          <div class="two-cols">
            <div>
              <label for="fName">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" required/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="lName">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="phoneNum">Phone Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="phoneNum" id="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="stAddress">Street Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="stAddress" id="stAddress" placeholder="Street Address: Line 1" required/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="province">Province <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="province" id="province" required>
              <option value="Abra">Abra</option>
              <option value="Agusan del Norte">Agusan del Norte</option>
              <option value="Agusan del Sur">Agusan del Sur</option>
              <option value="Aklan">Aklan</option>
              <option value="Albay">Albay</option>
              <option value="Antique">Antique</option>
              <option value="Apayao">Apayao</option>
              <option value="Aurora">Aurora</option>
              <option value="Basilan">Basilan</option>
              <option value="Bataan">Bataan</option>
              <option value="Batanes">Batanes</option>
              <option value="Batangas">Batangas</option>
              <option value="Biliran">Biliran</option>
              <option value="Benguet">Benguet</option>

            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="city">City <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="city" id="city" placeholder="Please select a city" required>
              <option value="Alaminos">Alaminos</option>
              <option value="Angeles">Angeles</option>
              <option value="Antipolo">Antipolo</option>
              <option value="Bacolod">Bacolod</option>
              <option value="Bacoor">Bacoor</option>
              <option value="Bago">Bago</option>
              <option value="Baguio">Baguio</option>
              <option value="Bais">Bais</option>
              <option value="Balanga">Balanga</option>

            </select>
          </div>

        </section>
        <section id="payMethod">

          <h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 10px;">Select Payment Method</h2>

          <div class="payment-method">
            <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="BDO" id="bdo" required/>
            <label class="pay-label" for="bdo"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="BDO icon"/>
                        <p>BDO Online Installment</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Up to 12 months installment term based on installment price. Promo price may not be applicable.</p>
                    </label>

          </div>

          <div class="payment-method">
            <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="Metrobank" id="metrobank" />
            <label class="pay-label" for="metrobank"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="Metrobank icon"/>
                        <p>Metrobank Online Installment</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Up to 12 months installment term based on installment price. Promo price may not be applicable.</p>
                    </label>

          </div>

          <div class="payment-method">

            <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="COD" id="cod" />
            <label class="pay-label" for="cod"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="Cash on Delivery icon"/>
                        <p>Cash on Delivery</p>
                        <p class="pay-description">Within P30,000 and Metro Manila, Cavite, Laguna only.</p>
                    </label>
          </div>

          <div class="payment-method">
            <input type="radio" name="paymentOpt" value="GCash" id="gcash" />
            <label class="pay-label" for="gcash"> <img class="payImg" src="https://www.firstbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt="GCash icon"/>
                        <p>GCash</p>
                        <!--<p class="pay-description">Within P30,000 and Metro Manila, Cavite, Laguna only.</p>-->
                    </label>

          </div>

          <input type="submit" value="PLACE ORDER">
        </section>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>




</body>

</html>
```